# How to get pandas to return the row index on which a CSV read error occurs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV: `'1\n2\na'`. If I read it with something like `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('1\n2\na'), names=['A'], dtype={'A': 'float'})` specifying that the first column has a type of integer, how can I get the row index at which the error occurred?

Pandas raises `ValueError` but only with the not-sufficiently-specific information that the error occurred with some input (in this case, `a`).

(My actual data is multi-billion row with 350 columns, this is obviously a simplification of the actual problem. The actual problem is that somewhere in these billions of rows and hundreds of columns, something somewhere has the word `Middlesex` rather than a number.)

Answer (score 0):

**Just a thought**

> Why not get help from regex? .

You'll have manual labour on your hand to fill in the missing records still though:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('1\n2\na'), names=['A'], dtype={'A': 'str'})
df.A = df.A.str.extract('(\d+)')
print(df)
```